# Delays for certain amount of agents

Tags: java, anylogic

I have been working on AnyLogic for the past few weeks and I can't seem to find a way for an event to trigger a stopDelay() for a certain amount of agents. For example, I just wish to end the delay for only 15 of the agents currently in the Delay block. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I tried running the code but I get an error in the for argument "delayBlock" part... int iAgentsStopped = 0;        
int iAgentsToStop = min(delay.size(), 15 );  
// if we have any to stop
if( iAgentsToStop > 0 ){
   for( Productos productoses : delayBlock )    /
      delay.stopDelay( productoses );
      iAgentsStopped++;         /* se 
      // if we have stopped enough, just stop looping
      if( iAgentsStopped == iAgentsToStop )    
         break;        
   }

Answer (score 1):

In an event (or any function), you could iterate over the delay block to stop the first 15 agents you find. The code could look something like this:

```
// assume delayBlock is the name of your delay block
int iAgentsStopped = 0;
int iAgentsToStop = min( delayBlock.size(), 15 ); // can't stop more than you have
// if we have any to stop
if( iAgentsToStop > 0 ){
   for( Agent agent : delayBlock ){
      delayBlock.stopDelay( agent );
      iAgentsStopped++;
      // if we have stopped enough, just stop looping
      if( iAgentsStopped == iAgentsToStop )
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: correction on your second line: min(delayBlock.size(),15);

Comment: I tried running the code but I get an error in the for argument "delayBlock" part... int iAgentsStopped = 0;        
int iAgentsToStop = min(delay.size(), 15 );  
// if we have any to stop
if( iAgentsToStop > 0 ){
   for( Productos productoses : delayBlock )    /
      delay.stopDelay( productoses );
      iAgentsStopped++;         /* se 
      // if we have stopped enough, just stop looping
      if( iAgentsStopped == iAgentsToStop )    
         break;        
   }

Comment: "delay" or "delay block" is meant to be whatever you have named your delay block.  I will add a comment to the original post

Comment: I am still having a problem since I get the following error: break cannot be outside of a loop or a switch, when I made the correction...

Comment: Add a bracket at end of for loop.  My typo in original  post, but if you are going to program in AnyLogic, you would really benefit from some basic coding practice - how to write for loops, etc

Answer (score 1):

This is a code that stops the agents in the delay block randomly instead of doing it by order of arrival:

```
int iAgentsStopped = 0;
int iAgentsToStop = min( delay.size(), 15 ); 
List <Agent> agents=findAll(delay,d->true);
Collections.shuffle(agents);
while(iAgentsStopped < iAgentsToStop){
     delay.stopDelay( agents.get(iAgentsStopped) );
     iAgentsStopped++;
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed this in the intellisense on the delay.get( i ) method?

"Returns the agent by index.
Note that this method is very slow and moreover the order of agents and their indexes aren't preserved and may be different at the next time moment"  I was surprised to see this & went back to AnyLogic 6.9 - it explicitly said ordered by oldest.  Have you ever had a time where it was not ordered or have you ever seen it just shuffled for you?

Comment: ups no... i made a mistake... it was agents.get, not delay.get :)